# Convert to unicode from UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, gmail, jakarta-mail, hebrew

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert UTF8 to unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049740/how-to-convert-utf8-to-unicode)

I am building an email client with JavaMail. I have a problem with getting non-English info from gmail.com.

For example, when I have a document with a filename in hebrew (`בעיה במודל.docx`), and I call:

```
part.getFileName()
```

then the result is `=?UTF-8?B?15HXoteZ15Qg15HXnteV15PXnC5kb2N4?=`.

I know that Unicode conversion is required, but I can't find out how.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049740/how-to-convert-utf8-to-unicode

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question (anyway, someone already answered), but I urge you to get your terminology right because there is a lot of confusion on this topic. Unicode is a set of standards of which the most important part is a character set. A character set is a mapping between code points (abstract integer values) and characters. UTF-8, part of Unicode, is one of several encodings defined by the standard that is used to take those code points and encode them into a byte stream. As such, you cannot "Convert to unicode from UTF-8", so the title of your question is nonsense.