# How to convert UTF-8 to unicode in Java?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

For example, in Emoji Char set, `U+1F601` is the unicode value for "GRINNING FACE WITH SMILING EYES", and `\xF0\x9F\x98\x81` is the UTF-8 bytes value for this character.

`\xE2\x9D\xA4` is for heavy black heart, and the unicode is `U+2764`.

So my question is, if I have a byte array with value `(0xF0, 0x9F, 0x98, 0x81, 0xE2, 0x9D, 0xA4)`, then how I can convert it into Unicode value?

For the above result, what I want is a String array with value `"1F601"` and `"2764"`.

I know I can write a complex method to do this work, but I hope there is already a library to do this work.

Comment: You can refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049740/how-to-convert-utf8-to-unicode).this question is already answered.

Comment: Do you just need a Unicode String or do you actually need the value 1F601? Because for the latter you'll need [`String.codePointAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt(int)) *in addition* the producing the `String` as explained in the answers.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, this is what I want. Thanks for pointing out the method codePointAt. Here I updated my question to make it clear. Can you have a look again? Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain how to convert the `UTF-8` values into the `unicode`? When I use the code below, it gives me the emoji instead of the `unicode` values such as `U+1F60`1. @XWang

Answer (score 8):

> So my question is, if I have a byte array with value (0xF0, 0x9F, 0x98, 0x81), then how I can convert it into Unicode value?

Simply call the `String` constructor specifying the data and the encoding:

```
String text = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
```

You can specify a `Charset` instead of the name of the encoding - I like [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s simple [`Charsets`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Charsets.html) class, which allows you to write:

```
String text = new String(bytes, Charsets.UTF_8);
```

Or for Java 7, use [`StandardCharsets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) without even needing Guava:

```
String text = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: If you use Java 7's `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets` you don't even need Guava

Comment: @artbristol: Thanks - I had a quick look, but missed that. Will edit it in.

Comment: @JonSkeet please what's the equivalent in .net or c#

Comment: @CharlesO: You'd use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text)`, and in reverse, `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I seem to be looking for the wrong thing here... Yes i'm aware we can use the GetBytes and GetString this is what i was unclear about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151972/convert-utf-8-hex-into-emoji-representation

Comment: @CharlesO: Okay - I was giving the .NET equivalent of the code in my question, which is what I thought you were after. So do you now have everything you need?

Comment: @JonSkeet Not quite, please see the the question I linked to. above. thanks

Comment: @CharlesO: Ah, I thought you'd linked to a different question. Will look now.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `String` class:

```
byte[] bytesArray = new byte[10]; // array of bytes (0xF0, 0x9F, 0x98, 0x81)

String string = new String(bytesArray, Charset.forName("UTF-8")); // covert byteArray

System.out.println(string); // Test result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using InputStreamReader:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("utf-8-text.txt");
Reader      reader      = new InputStreamReader(inputStream,
                                                Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

int data = reader.read();
while(data != -1){
    char theChar = (char) data;
    data = reader.read();
}

reader.close();
```

Ref:[Java I18N example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-internationalization/unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to convert UNICODE (ISO_8859_1) to UTF-8

```
public static String String_ISO_8859_1To_UTF_8(String strISO_8859_1) {
final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < strISO_8859_1.length(); i++) {
  final char ch = strISO_8859_1.charAt(i);
  if (ch <= 127) 
  {
      stringBuilder.append(ch);
  }
  else 
  {
      stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02x", (int)ch));
  }
}
String s = stringBuilder.toString();
int len = s.length();
byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
    data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                         + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
}
String strUTF_8 =new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
return strUTF_8;
}
```

**TEST**

```
String strA_ISO_8859_1_i = new String("الغلاف".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);

System.out.println("ISO_8859_1 strA est = "+ strA_ISO_8859_1_i + "\n String_ISO_8859_1To_UTF_8 = " + String_ISO_8859_1To_UTF_8(strA_ISO_8859_1_i));
```

**RESULT**

> ISO_8859_1 strA est = Ø§ÙØºÙØ§Ù  String_ISO_8859_1To_UTF_8 = الغلاف