# convert UTF-8 HEX into emoji representation

Tags: c#, utf-8, hex, emoji

How do we convert UTF-8 HEX: **EE 94 93**  into equivalent Emoji representation: 1f1e8, 1f1f3

taken from here: http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/175/places/regional-indicator-symbol-letters-cn

Comment: `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(new byte[] { 238, 148, 147 })`

Comment: @cdhowie that wont give you the  equivalent Emoji representation: 1f1e8, 1f1f3 at all

Comment: @cdhowie i've clarified my question

Comment: It gives you the softbank codepoint.  If you are wanting it to be expanded to the unified equivalent then you are going to need a huge table to map one onto the other. (Basically a `Dictionary<char, string>`.)

Comment: @cdhowie this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606523/how-to-convert-utf-8-to-unicode-in-java does it in java, i'm looking for the equivalent in  .net

Comment: What I provided is the equivalent. You are trying to do more than just decode UTF-8, you are trying to map one Unicode codepoint to something else entirely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62297/discussion-between-charleso-and-cdhowie).

Comment: Indeed - as the web page shows, the Unicode UTF-8 representation (which is what I think most people would assume when you just ask about UTF-8) is F0 9F 87 A8, F0 9F 87 B3.

Comment: @JonSkeet is there a conversion formula or do we need a manual dictionary lookup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string ConvertEmoji2UnicodeHex(string emoji)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emoji))
                return emoji;

            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(emoji);
            string firstItem = Convert.ToString(bytes[0], 2);  

            int iv;
            if (bytes.Length == 1)
            {
                iv = Convert.ToInt32(firstItem, 2);
            }
            else
            {
                StringBuilder sbBinary = new StringBuilder();
                sbBinary.Append(firstItem.Substring(bytes.Length + 1).TrimStart('0'));
                for (int i = 1; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    string item = Convert.ToString(bytes[i], 2);
                    item = item.Substring(2);
                    sbBinary.Append(item);
                }

                iv = Convert.ToInt32(sbBinary.ToString(), 2);
            }

            return Convert.ToString(iv, 16).PadLeft(4, '0');
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are discouraged. Try to explain how your answer solves the OPs problem. You may want to read about [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: please add description, how this code snippet will work.