# convert charset X to unicode in Java

Tags: java, html, character-encoding

How do you convert a specific charset to unicode in Java?

<s>charsets have been discussed quite a lot here, but I think this one hasn't been covered yet.</s>

I have a hex-string that meets the criteria `length%4==0` (e.g. `\ud3faef8e`). usually I just display this in an HTML container and add `&#x` to the front and `;` to the back of each hex quadruple.

but in this case the following procedure led to the correct output (non-Java)

1. paste hex string into Hex-Editor and save the file to `test.txt` (utf-8)
2. open the file with Notepad++
3. change the encoding to Simplified Chinese (GB2312)

Now I'm trying to do the same in Java.

```
// having hex convert to ascii
String ascii = "";
for (int cnt = 0; cnt <= unicode.length() - 2; cnt += 2) {
  String tmp = unicode.substring(cnt, cnt + 2);
  int decimal = Integer.parseInt(tmp, 16);
  ascii += (char) decimal;
}
// writing ascii to file at this point leads to the same result as in step 2 before
try {
  // get the bytes
  byte[] utf8 = ascii.getBytes("UTF-8"); // == UTF8
  // convert to gb2312
  String converted = new String(utf8, "GB2312"); // == EUC_CN
  // write to file (writer with declared UTF-8)
  writeToFile(converted, 20 + cntu);
  cntu++;
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

the output looks according the should-output, except the fact that randomly the following character is displayed: � why does this one come up? and how can I get rid of it?

in the end, what I'd like to get is the *converted* unicode again to be able to display it with my original approach (`&#xd3f4;`), but I haven't figured out a way to get to the hex values again (they don't match the criteria `length%4==0`). how do I get the hex values of the characters?

**update1**

to be more precise, regarding the input, I'm assuming that it is Unicode, because of the start of the String with `\u`, which would be sufficient for my usual approach, but not in the case I am describing above.

**update2**

the writeToFile method

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test" + id + ".txt");
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF8");
out.write(str);
out.close();
```

I tried with `GB2312` as well, but there is no change. I still get the *?* inbetween the correct characters.

**update3**

the expected output for `\ud3f6ef8e` is 遇飵 , you get to it when following the steps 1 to 3. (HxD as an example of an hex editor)

Comment: it looks very much like you're solving the wrong problem here. Why are you converting to a non-unicode codepage (chinese in this case) to begin with? If the target is an HTML file, generate it with the `<meta charset="utf-8">` element so the browser will render the unicode as unicode. Once your data is UTF-8, don't touch it. That's the encoding it should be forever.

Comment: you'r totally right, usually I don't do that, but in this case this is the only way I can come to the correct, expected result respectively (the steps I described with hex-editor, notepad++).

Comment: so where is your data coming from that it's 4-byte aligned hex? (note that UTF-8 is not 4-byte aligned). UTF-32 data?

Comment: sorry, I meant 4 hex values aligned, I updated the question with an example input. it's just a string of the following format `\ud3faef8e` .

Comment: `//writer with declared UTF-8` well the `String` is with GB2312 but the writer is writing with UTF-8? What is the `writeToFile` implementation?

Comment: see **update2** for the method's implementation. thanks

Comment: `\ud3fa` looks like a valid UTF-16 encoded code unit but what is `ef8e` supposed to represent? What hex editor accepts the format you discuss? What is the expected output? `ef` can't be ASCII because ASCII stops at `7F`. `ef8e` doesn't represent a supported byte sequence in ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 or GB2312.

Comment: see **update3** for the expected output, which I can only produce when doing the steps with hex-editor and notepad++.

Comment: @divadpoc question about your update 3. Which charset are you assuming on the input here, to reach the conclusion that it's supposed to be 遇飵? As unicode codepoints, that string is supposed to be "폶", for instance. The characters you say it should be do not match the hex prints in any known codepage: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9047/index.htm, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/98F5/index.htm

Comment: that is what bothers me, and you are right, the string is supposed to be "폶". I'm trying to figure out how I can get the *expected* output. to answer your question, I am assuming I get Unicode code points, encoded in UTF-8

Comment: I was misinterpreting the incoming hex-digits. they were in a specific charset and not uni-code, so they represented the hex-values of a character in that charset. What I'm doing now is `new String(byteArray, "CharsetName");` and get `(int)s.charAt(i)` to get the unicode value and write it to HTML. I think I can delete the question as it's just about how to convert charset to unicode, if you agree, please let me know. nevertheless, thanks for your ideas and hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was no indication that I should delete my question, thus I'm writing my final comment as the answer

I was misinterpreting the incoming hex-digits. they were in a specific charset and not uni-code, so they represented the hex-values of a character in that charset. What I'm doing now is new `String(byteArray, "CharsetName");` and get `(int)s.charAt(i)` to get the unicode value and write it to HTML. thanks for your ideas and hints

for more details see this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4049781/1338732 , and this question here: [How to convert UTF-8 to unicode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606523/how-to-convert-utf-8-to-unicode-in-java)

Comment: Deleting the question might be excessive, but you should at least rephrase it to make the whole combination easier to read. I.e. knowing now that the incoming characters are in a given charset, phrase it as "how to decode characters from charset X encoded as a hex string?"

Comment: true, but it would be a duplicate then, and anyhow deleted/marked as duplicate, thus no new information would be available with this question. how to get from a known charset to unicode was asked and answered before, in the beginning I just didn't know that I was misinterpreting the input, only with the comments I questioned my initial interpretation. that was the reason I wanted to delete it.

Comment: but, I can also rephrase it, I just didn't want to post a duplicate

Comment: How does the question, as stand, make any new information available then? "At one point divadpoc made a wrong guess about his input?"

Comment: in the end there is no new information/no new solution as I was mistaken about the problem I had to solve. the problem is now solved with the information presented in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606523/how-to-convert-utf-8-to-unicode-in-java - I would have to rephrase my question to: how to convert charset X to unicode